ksql dont see datagen connector previously installed and being in the components directory
I am passing through Clickstream Data Analysis Pipeline Using ksqlDB tutorial by Confluent. Tried this both on my Mac and on Ubuntu-based VPS
When I run
RUN SCRIPT '/scripts/create-connectors.sql';

command, I get the following error:

Validation error: {"error_code":500,"message":"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.kafka.connect.datagen.DatagenConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector, name='io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector', version='10.0.2', encodedVersion=10.0.2, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='file:/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-elasticsearch/'}"}

But here's content of components directory in ksql-server container (same in local directory passed into container by docker-compose):
docker compose exec ksqldb-server ls /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/
confluentinc-kafka-connect-datagen  confluentinc-kafka-connect-elasticsearch

Another list:
ksql> show connectors;

 Connector Name                     | Type | Class                                                         | Status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 es_sink_ERRORS_PER_MIN_ALERT       | SINK | io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector | RUNNING (1/1 tasks RUNNING)
 es_sink_ENRICHED_ERROR_CODES_COUNT | SINK | io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector | RUNNING (1/1 tasks RUNNING)
 es_sink_EVENTS_PER_MIN             | SINK | io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector | RUNNING (1/1 tasks RUNNING)
 es_sink_PAGES_PER_MIN              | SINK | io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector | RUNNING (1/1 tasks RUNNING)
 es_sink_USER_IP_ACTIVITY           | SINK | io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector | RUNNING (1/1 tasks RUNNING)
 es_sink_CLICK_USER_SESSIONS        | SINK | io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector | RUNNING (1/1 tasks RUNNING)
 es_sink_ERRORS_PER_MIN             | SINK | io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector | RUNNING (1/1 tasks RUNNING)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Another one from inside of ksql-server container:
curl -s localhost:8083/connector-plugins
[{"class":"io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"10.0.2"}]


I have faced with the same issue!
Just make sure that you have downloaded the connectors properly and mount is done correctly.

for me I was getting issues because of docker-compose.yaml file saying "$PWD" is not set i replaced all "$PWD" with '.'(dot) and it set mount properly.
After that you will be able to solve this issue.
You also might get issues related to windows_styleline_ending just convert all *.sh files into unix based line ending and it will work.

after solving this issue, you will get few more issues just try replacing this links instead of given links in tutorials
replace(docker-compose exec elasticsearch bash -c '/scripts/elastic-dynamic-template.sh')->
with
(docker-compose exec elasticsearch bash -c '../../../scripts/elastic-dynamic-template.sh')
replace(docker-compose exec ksqldb-server bash -c '/scripts/ksql-tables-to-grafana.sh')->
with(docker-compose exec ksqldb-server bash -c '../../scripts/ksql-tables-to-grafana.sh')
